# custom item labels in markdown

Tags: list, latex, markdown

In latex the following produces a nice output ([more examples here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/318441/framed-and-itemize-with-custom-item-labels))

```
\begin{itemize}
\item[$ABC$]  Definition and details of $ABC$.
\item[$EFG-PQE$] Definition and details of $EFG$ and Definition and details of $PQR$. Writing this sentence to make it multiline. 
\end{itemize}
```

[image]

How to get similar output in Markdown (.md) file?

Comment: LaTeX questions are okay here but [Can we have a ruling on LaTeX on Stack Overflow? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stack-overflow) may be better... but Markdown I'm not sure.

Comment: @user202729 markdown questions fit perfectly fine on SO, there are already thousands of them here

Comment: @RuaosP1 You can use the very same tex code as in your question in markdown documents. As long as you export to pdf this works fine.

Comment: ohh, I'm checking using preview in vscode. I prefer a non-pdf version for now. (for pdf anyway, I can use latex, why convert to md)

Comment: Which Markdown processor are you using? Markdown itself doesn't support definition lists, but some implementations have added them. The syntax varies, though.

Comment: ohh, md finally will be uploaded to gitlab; while writing in vscode, using preview functionality. I think the table can be good use in the mentioned scenario (without heading, two-columns, right align and left align respectively). However, I don't like the top horizontal line, is it possible to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

We need to consider the format this Markdown is intended to end up in.

Given that GitLab renders Markdown to HTML, [description lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) are your best bet:

```html
<dl>
  <dt>ABC</dt>
  <dd>Definition and details of ABC.</dd>

  <dt>EFG-PQE</dt>
  <dd>Definition and details of EFG and Definition and details of PQR.</dd>
</dl>
```

The list itself is defined by a `<dl>` tag. Terms go into a `<dt>` and descriptions go into a `<dl>`.

Since [GitLab-Flavored Markdown](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html) has no special syntax for description lists, you'll have to use [inline HTML](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#inline-html). And since [Markdown is not normally processed in block-level HTML tags](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html), if you want to format the terms in italics, as your rendered LaTeX example shows, you'll have to do one of two things:

1. Use inline HTML again:

   ```html
   <dl>
     <dt>ABC</dt>
     <dd>Definition and details of <em>ABC</em>.</dd>
     <!--                          ^^^^   ^^^^^   -->
   </dl>
   ```

   This option should work with pretty much any Markdown tool.
2. Put the Markdown content on its own line, separated from the HTML by whitespace:

   ```html
   <dl>
     <dt>ABC</dt>
     <dd>

     Definition and details of _ABC_.

     </dd>
   </dl>
   ```

   This option works in GitLab- and GitHub-Flavored Markdown. It also seems to work in Visual Studio Code's Markdown preview and on Stack Overflow.

Exactly how this gets rendered depends on the CSS being applied. Here's how Stack Overflow displays description lists:

ABC

Definition and details of ABC.

EFG-PQE

Definition and details of EFG and Definition and details of PQR.

And here is how it looks in a `README.md` on GitLab:

[image: Screenshot]